# Should I sell off my Traditional IRA holdings in the first year I stop working after 60?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, retirement

Just to experiment with Roth IRA and Traditional IRA, I do have both. I have some holdings in Traditional IRA, but they are more like US$1000 and a few hundred dollars in some other firms.

So let's say if I work until the age of 61, and at 62, I completely stop working and have no income. At this point, is it just better to sell the Traditional IRA holdings and keep the Roth IRA holdings? (assuming I won't claim social security until the age of 67 or 70). Then the Traditonal IRA holdings sale is tax free if my gain is under something like $20,000. (roughly speaking, the first $20,000 income is tax free).

That's because I can let the Roth IRA holdings grow, and they are not subject to tax, but the Traditional IRA holdings are subject to tax, so when it is a "no income year", I had better sell the Traditional IRA holdings first?

Comment: Have you checked existing answers? Yes, the rule of thumb is to sell non-tax-sheltered investments first, then traditional 401k/IRA/equivalent (taxed only at withdrawal), then Roth 401/IRA/equivalent (taxed only at deposit). You may want to rebalance your tax-sheltered accounts as you spend down the taxable, to maintain your desired investment mix.

Comment: Why is the first $20k of income tax free exactly?

Comment: @keshlam does it matter to sell stocks in a regular individual account vs in Traditional IRA? If in Traditional IRA, it is not tax sheltered just like a regular account

Comment: @littleadv isn't it due to standard deduction, etc, the first $20,000 income won't be subject to any tax?

Comment: Standard deduction, for a single filer, is less than 20k, what's "etc"?

Comment: Traditional IRA is still avoiding taxes on growth, which is the point of IRA versus general investment after all.  So, yes, sell other investments first.

Comment: @keshlam not avoiding, deferring.

Comment: True. Unfortunately we can't edit comments.

Answer (score 4):

When you withdraw money from traditional IRA, it is considered "ordinary" income, i.e.: income taxed at the marginal rate.

Assuming you're a Single taxpayer, with $13,850 standard deduction. You withdrew $20,000 from your traditional IRA. Assuming you're not entitled to any other credits or deductions and have no other income, your AGI would be $20,000, and $6,150 would be your taxable income.

The marginal rate for the first $10,000 of your taxable income is 10%, so your Federal tax would be $615. You'll need to do similar calculations for State tax.

Generally when you are in a low income year and you expect your income to grow - it's a good opportunity to *convert* your funds from traditional IRA to Roth IRA, pay the low tax, and let the money continue growing tax free.

If you have taxable investments, it is also a good opportunity to utilize the capital gains tax rates for long term capital gains: if your *total* taxable income is up to $41,675 - you pay 0% (zero, nothing) capital gains tax (with some specific exceptions).

Source from the IRS for the marginal rates [for ordinary income](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-provides-tax-inflation-adjustments-for-tax-year-2023) and [for capital gains](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc409).